# PHP passing value to a class

Tags: php, class, constructor

I have a class called DatabaseController which I've set up as so:

```
<?php

class DBController {

    public $dbName;

    function _controller($passedDBName) { 
        $dbName = $passedDBName;
    }

    function dbConnect() { 
        print $this->$dbName;
    }



} //end of class       
?>
```

and I am calling it this way:

```
<?php

    //make new database connection
    $dbManager = new DBController("somevalue");
    $dbManager->dbConnect();


?>
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot access empty property in
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the constructor, `$dbName = $passedDBName;` should be `$this->dbName = $passedDBName;`.

**Update:**

1. `$this->$dbName` should be `$this->dbName`.
2. `_controller()` should be `__construct()`.

Comment: The error is because `dbConnect()` tries to access an unitialized variable. The variable is unitialized because in the constructor you type `$dbName = $passedDBName;`, which should be `$this->dbName = $passedDBName;`.

Comment: That's incorrect. `$this->$dbName` accesses the field with the name that is stored in `$dbName`.  And since `$dbName` is not set it tries to access a field with an empty name - and **that** causes the fatal error. Reading an undefined field just results in a notice. - see http://codepad.org/Zu6yQuno

Comment: Ah I see. I just noticed the second `$` in `$this->$dbName`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$this->dbName` - otherwise you try to access a field whose name is stored in `$dbName`. You also need to fix your constructur to assign to `$this->dbName` instead of `$dbName`.

```
class DBController {
    public $dbName;
    function _controller($passedDBName) { 
        $this->dbName = $passedDBName;
    }
    function dbConnect() { 
        print $this->dbName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Who the hell is downvoting a correct answer without leaving a comment?

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer after the 15-minute delay is over. And since you seem to be rather new with PHP consider having a look at the PHP documentation - it is pretty good.

Comment: I am just curious is _controller a constructor name? Can I specify my own name of a constructor in a class? I can't find about it in the manual. I have no interest of doing it - But I am however curious.

Comment: The constructor is always called `__construct`. So `_controller` has no special meaning for PHP at all. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php for a list of all possible magic methods.